# How to cleanly expose C++ backend objects to QML, for varying setContextProperties?

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt5, qqmlapplicationengine

I am creating a QML Application with a C++ backend. Different types of cameras can connect to my C++ backend. These cameras have different types of sensors and different numbers of batteries, etc. Depending on what type of Camera is connected, the C++ backend exposes objects to QML using `setContextProperty()`.

Due to the method I am currently using, I have to check what kind of camera is connected (`camInfo.type`) in QML, and depending on that, bind to the appropriate backend object. This is used throughout my QML Application, so a lot of switch-casing is done, and it is very unmaintainable to support a new camera model.

Is there another way I can expose the varying backend objects to QML, for each different camera model? I do not want to use any switch-cases on `camInfo.type` in QML.

It would be preferable if I could do something like:

```
Text {                                         
    y: 50                                      
    x: 50                                      
    text: camera.sensor0Data.sensorReading                                     
    }                                          
}
```

where `camera.sensor0Data.sensorReading` would somehow "map" to one of `apertureData.sensorReading`, `sensor0Data.sensorReading` etc. in the backend. And the `Text` would be `visible:false` if the connected camera doesn't include that specific sensor.

**Snippet of main.qml**

```
Text {                                         
    y: 50                                      
    x: 50                                      
    text: {                                    
        switch(camInfo.type){                  
        case 0: // DSLR                        
            apertureData.sensorReading         
            break                              
        case 1: //MOBILE                       
            sensor0Data.sensorReading          
            break                              
        case 2: //PointandShoot                
            sensor0Data.sensorReading          
        }                                      
    }                                          
}                                              

Text {                                         
    visible: camInfo.type==2 // Point and Shoot
    y: 90                                      
    x: 90                                      
    text: {                                    
        switch(camInfo.type){                  
        case 0: // DSLR                        
        case 1: //MOBILE                       
            "N/A"                              
            break                              
        case 2: //PointandShoot                
            microphoneData.sensorReading       
        }                                      
    }                                          
}
```

**backend.cpp**

```
#include "backend.h"
#include <QQmlContext>

enum Model {
    // types of cameras.
    DSLR=0,
    MOBILE_CAMERA,
    POINT_AND_SHOOT
};

Backend::Backend(QQmlApplicationEngine* engine, QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent)
{
    // Connecting back end object instances to front end
    QQmlContext* ctxt(engine->rootContext());
    ctxt->setContextProperty("camInfo", deviceInfo);
    ctxt->setContextProperty("videoFeedData", videoFeedData); //video.h

    switch(deviceInfo->m_type){
        case DSLR:
            ctxt->setContextProperty("battery0Data", battery0Data); // battery.h
            ctxt->setContextProperty("battery1Data", battery1Data); // battery.h
            ctxt->setContextProperty("battery2Data", battery2Data); // battery.h
            ctxt->setContextProperty("apertureData", apertureData); // aperture.h
            ctxt->setContextProperty("sensor1Data", sensor1Data); // sensor.h
            ctxt->setContextProperty("sensor2Data", sensor2Data); // sensor.h
            ctxt->setContextProperty("sensor3Data", sensor3Data); // sensor.h
            break;
        case MOBILE_CAMERA:
            ctxt->setContextProperty("sensor0Data", sensor0Data); // sensor.h
            ctxt->setContextProperty("batteryData", batteryData); // battery.h
            break;
        case POINT_AND_SHOOT:
            ctxt->setContextProperty("microphoneData", microphoneData);
            ctxt->setContextProperty("sensor0Data", sensor0Data); // sensor.h
            ctxt->setContextProperty("batteryData", batteryData); // battery.h
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: provide a [mre]

Comment: @eyllanesc Ty for the reference. I believe I had provided the relevant reprex at the bottom of my post, for the question I was trying to ask. Would you like me to include the other cpp files in my minimal project, such that it can be run?

Comment: Hi, why not make a class like `class Camera: public QObject { Q_PROPERTY {SensorsModel sensors READ sensors NOTIFY sensorsChanged()} };`

Where `SensorsModel` can be a simple `QAbstractListModel` exposing a bunch of Sensor objects, something like say Sensor `{ type: "battery"; minValue: 0; maxValue: 100; value: 50}`. Then in the QML you can have a Loader loading various Views based on the camera type or have a single view that shows various sensor data based on your requirements

Comment: @Dinesh The idea of using a Loader to load various views appears to be the method to move forward with. Can you please add your suggestion as an answer to this post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [Dinesh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2563402/dinesh)'s comment, the idea of using a `Loader` to load various views appeared to be the method to move forward with. I am posting his answer here for now, to mark this question as answered. If [@Dinesh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2563402/dinesh) answers it, I will mark his answer as accepted instead.

Make a class like

```cpp
class Camera: public QObject {
    Q_PROPERTY (SensorsModel sensors READ sensors NOTIFY sensorsChanged()) 
};
```

Where `SensorsModel` can be a simple `QAbstractListModel` exposing a bunch of Sensor objects, something like say `Sensor { type: "battery"; minValue: 0; maxValue: 100; value: 50}`.

Then in the QML you can have a `Loader` loading various Views based on the camera type.